# Database Table Normalization

Tags: php, mysql

```
Table 1

id  Student
1   Ali
2   Akram
3   Aamir
4   Adeel
5   Aun

Table 2

id  Course
1   English
2   Urdu
3   Maths
4   Physics
5   Chemistry


Table 3

id  stu_id   course_id
1   1          1
2   1          2
3   2          1
4   2          5
5   5          1
```

Q1: Are these tables normalized ?

Q2:  Help me to remove duplicates from table 3, suppose if table 2 have 1000 courses, and student id 1 and 2 are enrolled in all courses, table 3 will be very large because of 2000 entries , is there any way to reduce these ?

Comment: You have correctly implemented many-to-many relationship.  2000 record table is not large at all.

Comment: What duplicates from table 3? Create a unique key on stu_id and course_id and you won't get any duplicates either. And you're talking very small amounts of data; there's no need to reduce it at all

Comment: In my opinion, the `id` column in Table3 is unnecessary. The logical key of the many-to-many table is `stu_id` and `course_id`. `id` is simply a surrogate, physical primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is normalized with a many-to-many relation;
2. Yes max cardinality of a many-to-many relation like that is max students x max courses, nothing terrible;
3. In many-to-many relationships use the multiple columns key of the ids couple, you do not need another id;
4. If by duplicates you mean the fact you have many equal fields in the columns, that are not duplicates at all. They mean that a student has many courses and viceversa. What has to be unique is the couple stu_id-course_id.

Regards